# Removing Linux Partition from Secondary drive

Tags: boot, partitioning, uninstall, windows-10

I have been tinkering with Ubuntu for a while in VMs and what not.  I recently decided to try a dual boot, but I wanted to keep my partition on my secondary drive.  I also put the GRUB bootloader on that drive as well.  Since I have don this dual boot I have been experiencing many problems with my primary drive which is running windows 10.  Essentially my windows 10 will freeze.  Windows won't close, I won't be able to access the start menu, the task bar freezes, and I can't access the task manager when this happens so I have decided it may be best to just go ahead and remove the linux partition and boot loader from that secondary drive since that is when the problems started.  Trouble is I'm not sure how to remove GRUB from that secondary drive.  Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does your computer boot from the first drive, when your second drive is disconnected?

Comment: Yes.  I have actually changed the boot drive in my bios from my secondary drive to my primary drive and it uses the windows mbr on the primary drive instead of GRUB.  When I change the boot order to boot from the secondary drive it goes to grub and gives me the option to boot from windows or Ubuntu since I kept GRUB on the secondary drive instead of the primary drive.  Regardless of what boot loader I use I still have the same problems.  Hence I want to remove Ubuntu and the GRUB entirely from my secondary drive and see if that works.

Comment: When you are sure that the computer boots, when the second drive is disconnected, is it straight-forward. Make the computer boot from the first drive, and you can have 'anything' in the second drive. The computer should not be bothered. So you can use a tool in Windows to 'format' that linux partition. The grub bootloader will still be there unless you overwrite it with something else. It should not be activated unless you try to boot from that drive. But if you need that second drive to boot, you must be more careful, and make the first drive able to boot before changing the second drive.

Comment: I got it figured out.  It wasn't the GRUB causing the issue it was a problem with Windows.  Backed up my files and did a fresh install.   All is well with the world.  I get to keep both my windows and my Linux environments. I like Linux better for tinkering and my Web Dev classes.  Thanks for responding.

Comment: Congratulations and good luck with Ubuntu and other linux distros :-)